# Rails/ActiveRecord, how to prevent pluck from overriding select?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

As an example, I want to run a query like

```
people = Person.select("GROUP_CONCAT(`first` SEPARATOR ', ') as names") \
.where(last: "smith").group(:age).order(:age)

# which basically gives me something like
# SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`first` SEPARATOR ', ') as names ...

#####################

# but when I add pluck
people.pluck(:names)
# it does
# SELECT names ...
# and gives me an Unknown column error
```

How do I make rails/activerecord to handle pluck on the result of the select query rather than overriding it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible. `pluck` will always override any select you specify. But you can do this:

```
people = Person.where(last: "smith").group(:age).order(:age)
people.pluck("GROUP_CONCAT(`first` SEPARATOR ', ')")
```

or this:

```
people = Person.select("GROUP_CONCAT(`first` SEPARATOR ', ') as names") \
.where(last: "smith").group(:age).order(:age)
people.all.collect(&:name)
```

Comment: You don't need the trailing "I want the `.` on the next line" backslash anymore.

Comment: Copy pasted from question, also what if he is using 1.8.7 :)

Comment: @Derek: mechanicalfish is right, you needed the escape in 1.8.7 to make it behave sensibly, newer Rubies are smart enough to do The Right Thing though.